# Django form wont validate?

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I am having trouble having my form validate in Django and I really dont know what the problem is.  It is a messaging application and I am trying to have the user sending the message be automatically populated with the user that is logged in.  I have tried a lot of things but none of them have worked. Any help would be appreciated.  Here is my models.py: (anything commented out is previous attempts at a solution)

```
class Message(models.Model):
#readonly_fields = 'sender'
sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="send", default=User)
recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receive", default=None)
message_subject = models.CharField("Subject", max_length=25)
message_text = models.TextField("Message")
message_time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
urgent = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=URGENCY)
#field to make message urgent or not

def __str__(self):
    return self.message_subject
```

here is the views.py for creating a new message: (anything commented out is previous attempts at a solution)(also includes@login_required tag that wouldnt show up when pasting)

```
def newMessage(request, user):
user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user)
#form = MessageForm(request.POST or None, initial={'sender':request.POST.get('username')})
if request.method == 'POST':
    #instance = Message(sender=request.user)
    #form = MessageForm(instance=instance)
    #form = MessageForm(initial={'sender':request.user})
    form = MessageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_instance = form.save()
        temp = Event(activity='\n' + new_instance.sender.get_full_name() + " sent a message to " +  new_instance.recipient.get_full_name())
        temp.save()

        try:
            target = Patient.objects.get(user=user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/patients/%s/' % target.id)
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                target = Nurse.objects.get(user=user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/nurses/%s/' % target.id)
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    target = Doctor.objects.get(user=user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/doctors/%s/' % target.id)
                except Exception as e:
                    try:
                        target = HospitalAdmin.objects.get(user=user)
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/hospitalAdmins/%s/' % target.id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        return render(request, "main_site/newMessagePrompt.html",
                                        { "form" : form, })
elif request.method == 'GET':
    form = MessageForm()
return render(request, "main_site/newMessagePrompt.html",
              { "form" : form, })
```

Here is the form:(anything commented out is previous attempts at a solution)

```
class MessageForm(ModelForm):
#readonly_fields = 'sender'
urgent = forms.ChoiceField(choices=URGENCY, required=True)
class Meta:
    model = Message
    #widgets = {'sender': forms.HiddenInput()}
    exclude =['message_time_created']
```

Currently, with giving the sender a default=User in the model, which does auto-populate with the user who is logged in, and if you try to send the message it will work.  However the field can still be edited, which is not intentional.  If i try to make the field editable=False in the model.py, and then try to send the message, it will give an error.  If i try other ways to hide this, such as HiddenInput in the form, the form will not validate.  Similar results have occurred when trying to use an instance variable.  I have also tried to make the sender field be a read only field but have not succesffully been able to implement it to see if it would work.  I really cannot figure out how to fix this problem.  Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: you can try using Custom form validators to validate as per your own needs. form.is_valid() checks or only some parameters, its not for your own specific usage.

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829305/django-how-to-validate-post-parameters/33830001#33830001

Comment: What does `form.errors` contain? What part of your form isn't valid?

Comment: This is a very frequently asked question here, and is also well covered in the docs. Exclude the user attribute from the form, call form.save(commit=False), and add the user to the resulting object before saving it. Also, you must never ever ever catch bare Exception; your code is swallowing all sorts of possible errors.